# Error: SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

Even though the syntax for the above prepared statement is corret I am getting the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Expected result is the following code must return the values for the table

```
try{
        conn = DatabaseMain.getConnection();
        String instqury = "Select quality_name,quality_size,quality_weight,quality_spec from quality where quality_code = '?'";
        pst1 = conn.prepareStatement(instqury);
        pst1.setString(1, quality);

        rs1 = pst1.executeQuery();
        rs1.next();
        name.setText(String.valueOf(rs1.getString("quality_name")));

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error in setting labels for Machine View");
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I haven't done java in a long time, but I'm pretty sure you should remove the single quotes around the ?, otherwise it gets treated as literal SQL and not as a placeholder. Therefore it does not expect a parameter and hence your error.

Comment: Don't quote the `?` (as everyone else has said). Also, it's a good idea to test you have a row with an `if` based on `rs1.next()` before trying to retrieve `quality_name`. And if you only want to read one column don't select three other columns. And why are you passing a `String` to `String.valueOf`? `name.setText(rs1.getString("quality_name"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the placeholder between single quotes:

```
String instqury = 
    "Select quality_name,quality_size,quality_weight,quality_spec " + 
    "from quality where quality_code = ?";
                                       ^-- here
```

Answer (score 1):

try removing single quotes from the placeholder ?, when you place like this '?' query is reading it as value provided.